# Aligning text to bottom of justified tabs (Bootstrap 3.3.6)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a working set of justified bootstrap tabs (Bootstrap 3.3.6). I need to vertically align the text along the bottom of the tabs.

http://www.bootply.com/l7byiP8RsS

I've tried setting the anchor tags to tables, absolute, relative position. All with undesirable effects.

This project is not intended for the public use and will be run on a modern browser. It can use the most advanced techniques. Any new CSS3 declarations I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

to your

.nav-tabs>li>a

is this what you wanted?

Comment: This works mostly. But it was leaving me with strange spacing between the tabs: http://imgur.com/a/yI4ZA

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
line-height: 45px;
```

to `.nav-tabs>li>a` and that worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I used [Aliysa's css from below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711112/2909501), which left me with [unsual spacing between the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiVb9.jpg). Changing nav-justified to width:auto fixed it. Probably broke something else, but it works in my case.

`.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li { width: auto; }`